# Correct placement of 'inline'

Tags: c++

Where do I put `inline` correctly?

---

test1.h:

```
class test1
{
    inline void method1() {}
};
```

---

test2.h:

```
class test2
{
    void method2();
};

inline void test2::method2() {}
```

---

test3.h:

```
class test3
{
    inline void method3();
};

inline void test3::method3() {}
```

---

test4.h:

```
class test4
{
    inline void method4();
};
```

test4.cpp:

```
void test4::method4() {}
```

---

test5.h:

```
class test5
{
    inline void method5();
};
```

test5.cpp:

```
inline void test5::method5() {}
```

---

test6.h:

```
class test6
{
    void method6();
};
```

test6.cpp:

```
inline void test6::method6() {}
```

---

test7.h:

```
class test7
{
    inline void method7();
};

void test7::method7() {}
```

---

(I'm used to code like in example 6, but read alot of `inline` and now im not sure about this anylonger)
Which of these examples is the correct useage of `inline`, why do they differ and are they all valid?

EDIT #1:
All these examples are indeed `private`, I didn't thought of `public` and `protected` in the first place. As stated in the comments there could occour major errors because of that.

Comment: IMHO Test 6 is essentially the same as Test 2 and both are correct (well, if doing what I do is "correct").

Comment: The use of `inline` as an optimization feature has basically outlived its usefulness. Today it is still used for the effect it has on linkage. However, this usage of `inline` is somewhat less than common, and if you're going for a "least surprised" programming style, you should probably avoid it if you can. Oh, and [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html).

Comment: Doesn't really matter, it'll be ignored anyway :)

Comment: @RogerRowland 6 is not correct.

Comment: @PaulEvans That's a quality of implementation issue.  A good compiler will _not_ ignore it.

Comment: @JamesKanze that's *very* heartening to know. Thanks :))

Comment: @JamesKanze: Depending on what you consider a "good" compiler. Wrong usage of `inline` could increase code size *and* decrease performance. I'd say a "good" compiler *would* ignore it in this case; your mileage may vary.

Comment: @DevSolar While it's true that the best state of the art profile based optimization can do a better job than the programmer at determining what can and should be inlined, very few compilers are at that level, and for most compilers, `inline` is a very important optimization hint.  (Or could be, if they'd use it.  If they don't, however, I'd have to consider it a major defect in the compiler.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Can you explain *why* 6 is not correct?

Comment: @DevSolar Wrong usage of anything can cause problems.  The point is that at present, most compilers are _not_ capable of doing a better job than the programmer at judging what should and should not be inlined.

Comment: @RogerRowland The implementation will not be visible at the call site.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ok, I see that, but does it affect usage in the cpp itself? So is it ok to do this for `private` functions? FWIW the OP's examples are all implicitly `private`.

Comment: @RogerRowland It would be OK for `private` functions, provided that they aren't invoked from any public inline functions, and that all of the public member functions which use them are in the same source file.  (If your writing a general purpose library, you'll probably want to put each function in a separate source file.)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't thought of the `private`/`public` hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4, 5, and 6 are (probably) wrong: inline functions must be defined in every translation unit that uses them, so these only allow the function to be used in one translation unit. This might be acceptable for a private function that's only called by other functions defined in the same source file, but prevents the more general usage that you usually want from a function declared in a header.

The others are all equivalent: they contain at least one inline declaration, and exactly one definition, in a header so that the definition can be included anywhere it's needed. (As long as the header is properly protected against re-inclusion, to prevent multiple definitions in a single translation unit).

In the first, the `inline` keyword is redundant: functions defined inside class definitions are implicitly inline.

I would advise against 3 and 7, since they require changing both the declaration and the definition if you later decide that the function shouldn't be inline. That leaves 1 and 2 as my preferred options; and I'd only use 1 for very short functions to avoid cluttering the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

All of your examples except 4, 5 and 6 are correct, provided you
don't call the function before a declaration with `inline` has
been seen.  In practice, 7 is about the only one I've seen in
successful large scale projects; for local classes, defined in
a source file, 1 is also used, but without the `inline` keyword
(which is implicit here).

Comment: You see 7 more than 2? I've had the opposite experience.

Comment: @Simple I've never seen 2 in actual code (although it is legal).

Comment: "provided you don't call the function before a declaration with inline has been seen" - why not? Is there some rule that neither I nor any of the compilers I use know about?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Now that you mention it, I'm not sure about that restriction.  It was present in CFront:-), and I've not really thought about the issue since.  Logically, one would expect the constraint, given the way C++ expects compilers to behave, but I can't find it offhand in the standard.  (Of course, if you're using 2, the issue doesn't come up.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not sure that our coding standard mandates (2) but I've never seen 7 in code where I work

Answer (score 1):

Test 4 I believe may give you a compile error because the compiler will be expecting the code within the file where declaration is. The inline keyword specifies where the actual body of the code is (in the same file, linkage) **as well as** inserting the complete body of the code where the function is called. The first part is important because if the body of the code is located in a different file than where you specified inline... the compile will fail.

Here is a short MSDN article showing an overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w2887zk.aspx